# how to build and return a result from a webapi controler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

So I have put together a group of stored procedure calls in my web api controller. Now I need to return the combined results. Javascript is as simple as something like this:

```
var result = [{
     objectResult: value
   },{
      arryResult1:[value]
   },{
      arryResult2:[value]
   }]
```

but it c# it would require a class that contains 2 lists and a object? then return that as a list? this is where i am kind of lost.

```
  [HttpPost]
    [Route("builderContact")]
    public List<usp_get_builder_contact_data_Result> GetBuilderContact(parameter parameter)
    {
        object[] parameters = { parameter.company_id, parameter.subdivision_id };

        var builderContact =  db.Database.SqlQuery<usp_get_builder_contact_data_Result>("sandbox.usp_get_builder_contact_data {0},{1}",
        parameters).First();

        var floorplanDataResult = db.Database.SqlQuery<usp_get_floorplan_data_Result>("sandbox.usp_get_floorplan_data {0},{1}",
        parameters).ToList();

        var floorplanRelatedResult = db.Database.SqlQuery<usp_get_floorplan_related_sections_Result>("sandbox.usp_get_floorplan_related_sections {0},{1}",
        parameters).ToList();

        return ?;
    }
```

update for answer

```
  [HttpPost]
    [Route("bigEnchilada")]
    public List<object> GetBuilderContact(parameter parameter)
    {
        object[] parameters = { parameter.company_id, parameter.subdivision_id };

        var builderContact = db.Database.SqlQuery<usp_get_builder_contact_data_Result>("sandbox.usp_get_builder_contact_data {0},{1}",
        parameters).First();

        var floorplanDataResult = db.Database.SqlQuery<usp_get_floorplan_data_Result>("sandbox.usp_get_floorplan_data {0},{1}",
        parameters).ToList();

        var floorplanRelatedResult = db.Database.SqlQuery<usp_get_floorplan_related_sections_Result>("sandbox.usp_get_floorplan_related_sections {0},{1}",
        parameters).ToList();

        return (new object[] {
                new object { builderContact = builderContact },
                new object { floorplanDataResult = floorplanDataResult },
                new object { floorplanRelatedResult = floorplanRelatedResult }
            }).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to match *exactly* what you have in Javascript, then change the return type to `List<object>` and return:

```
return new List<object> {
    new { objectResult = builderContact },
    new { arryResult1 = floorplanDataResult },
    new { arryResult2 = floorplanRelatedResult }
};
```

IMHO in this context the following model would be much more suited (if you can change it, that is):

```
var result = {
    objectResult: value,
    arryResult1: [value],
    arryResult2: [value]
}
```

In which case you would set the return type to `object` and return:

```
return new {
    objectResult = builderContact,
    arryResult1 = floorplanDataResult,
    arryResult2 = floorplanRelatedResult
};
```

A tiny bit nicer, no?

Comment: doesnt need to be like javascript. but to clarify your answer. The 'object' is that something i need to define with a class? see updated it post please

Comment: The `object` is built into C#

Comment: just saw your additional answers !

Comment: Please use the updated version as it's much cleaner and easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `concat` them all ?

```
List<object> allItems = (
                            from x in floorplanDataResult.ToList() select new object()
                        ).ToList().Concat(
                            from y in floorplanRelatedResult.ToList() select new object()
                        ).ToList();
return allItems;
```

I don't know if your client expects them in the same payload though...